# Replace blank spaces with %20 in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to validate a UITextField to replace a blank space ' ' with '%20' and was wondering how this is possible?

Comment: What does *"validate a UITextField to replace a blank space"* mean?

Comment: When the user inputs a text into the UITextField, for example 'Daylight by Maroon 5' this is then pushed onto a website, so the blank spaces are required to be %20 so therefor it would should 'Daylight%20by%20Maroon%205' Thanks

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Check out the method stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString: on [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) if you are just looking to replace the characters in a string with another value.

Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a target string in the receiver are replaced by another given string.

```
NSString *originalString = @"Sample text with spaces";

NSString *newString = [originalString stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
```

If you are attempting to encode a URL, use stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: on [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Returns a representation of the receiver using a given encoding to determine the percent escapes necessary to convert the receiver into a legal URL string.

```
NSString *originalString = @"Sample text with spaces";

NSString *newString = [originalString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Yep, that is the best way.

Comment: @Josiah Not really. Only way that would be 'best' would be if the OP knew that at no point any other URL unsafe chacters would be passed through the text field, which I'm guessing they can't.

Comment: @Jeremy1026, Yeah. I just saw the other answer. I didn't know about that. The alternative is way better.

Comment: @Dan  Did you really just downvote my answer and copy it to your own?

Comment: Thanks guys for all your help, I got her working with            NSString = [NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

Comment: Use this [originalString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet] ] and [encodedString stringByRemovingPercentEncoding] . So no need to use %20 replacement

Comment: To REMOVE the %20, use stringByRemovingPercentEncoding

Answer (score 19):

```
NSString* string = @"Daylight by Maroon 5" ;
NSString* encodedString = [string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
```

Comment: Note: if you want more fine-grained control over which characters should be escaped, you can drop down to Core Foundation and use [`CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes).

Comment: ... But this is even better! +1

Comment: And this will replace spaces with %20. But you have not specified %20? (Sorry I'm still a beginner at programming).

Comment: [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:) says that it "determines the percent escapes necessary to convert the receiver into a legal URL string". So yes, it'll replace [every character that needs to be percent-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) with the proper replacement set of characters.